# Remote authentication using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, authentication, oauth

I am trying to access SharePoint online using **REST API's** remotely. **Office 365 Smart links** are enabled for the site. As per [this](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/) blog I don't receive `wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken` in the response. My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
'url': 'https://sts.something.com/adfs/ls/?&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline&wctx=wa%3Dwsignin1.0%26rpsnv%3D4%26ct%3D1417151170%26rver%3D6.1.6206.0%26wp%3DMBI%26wreply%3Dhttps:%252F%252Fsomethingonline.sharepoint.com%252F_forms%252Fdefault.aspx%26lc%3D16393%26id%3D500046%26bk%3D1417151171%26LoginOptions%3D3',
           dataType: 'text',
     type:'POST',
'data': '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:40c1407d-b2a4-4e05-8248-8a92b71102b6</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2012-07-26T16:13:00.622Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2012-07-26T16:18:00.622Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-69882db9-2d6b-45d3-b016-c2156cb6c01d-1"><o:Username>userid@something.com</o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*********</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><a:EndpointReference><a:Address>https://somthingonline.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0</a:Address></a:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>',
          headers: {
        Accept : "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('done in login ');
        console.log('result '+result);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( result );
        console.log("xmlDoc:"+xmlDoc);
        var xml = $( xmlDoc )
        console.log("xml:"+xml);
        var binToken= xml.find( "wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken" ).text();
        console.log("Binary Token:"+binToken);
                                            alert("Binary Token:"+binToken);

        //  alert(  localStorage.getItem('BinaryToken') );
        wsignin(binToken);
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown+'error login:' + jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('login completed ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

My response in fiddler is as follows:

`<html><head><title>Working...</title></head><body><form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf"><input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" /><input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust&quot;>&lt;t:Lifetime>&lt;wsu:Created xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;>2014-11-28T18:37:25.272Z&lt;/wsu:Created>&lt;wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;>2014-11-28T19:37:25.272Z&lt;/wsu:Expires>&lt;/t:Lifetime>&lt;wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy&quot;>&lt;wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot;>&lt;wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline&lt;/wsa:Address>&lt;/wsa:EndpointReference>&lt;/wsp:AppliesTo>&lt;t:RequestedSecurityToken>&lt;saml:Assertion MajorVersion=&quot;1&quot; MinorVersion=&quot;1&quot; AssertionID=&quot;_7f55172b-43f9-466c-bede-436d794119e2&quot; Issuer=&quot;http://sts.something.com/adfs/services/trust&quot; IssueInstant=&quot;2014-11-28T18:37:25.274Z&quot; xmlns:saml=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion&quot;>&lt;saml:Conditions NotBefore=&quot;2014-11-28T18:37:25.272Z&quot; NotOnOrAfter=&quot;2014-11-28T19:37:25.272Z&quot;>&lt;saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline&lt;/saml:Audience>&lt;/saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;/saml:Conditions>&lt;saml:AttributeStatement>&lt;saml:Subject>&lt;saml:NameIdentifier Format=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified&quot;>ddcNR0t/6kWEAp4knvEteA==&lt;/saml:NameIdentifier>&lt;saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer&lt;/saml:ConfirmationMethod>&lt;/saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;/saml:Subject>&lt;saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot;UPN&quot; AttributeNamespace=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims&quot;>&lt;saml:AttributeValue>userid@something.COM&lt;/saml:AttributeValue>&lt;/saml:Attribute>&lt;saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot;ImmutableID&quot; AttributeNamespace=&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05&quot;>&lt;saml:AttributeValue>ddcNR0t/6kWEAp4knvEteA==&lt;/saml:AttributeValue>&lt;/saml:Attribute>&lt;/saml:AttributeStatement>&lt;saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password&quot; AuthenticationInstant=&quot;2014-11-28T18:37:24.943Z&quot;>&lt;saml:Subject>&lt;saml:NameIdentifier Format=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified&quot;>ddcNR0t/6kWEAp4knvEteA==&lt;/saml:NameIdentifier>&lt;saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer&lt;/saml:ConfirmationMethod>&lt;/saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;/saml:Subject>&lt;/saml:AuthenticationStatement>&lt;Signature xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot;>&lt;SignedInfo>&lt;CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#&quot; />&lt;SignatureMethod Algorithm=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1&quot; />&lt;Reference URI=&quot;#_7f55172b-43f9-466c-bede-436d794119e2&quot;>&lt;Transforms>&lt;Transform Algorithm=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature&quot; />&lt;Transform Algorithm=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#&quot; />&lt;/Transforms>&lt;DigestMethod Algorithm=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1&quot; />&lt;DigestValue>9Jldbpiqe7ie6Q4R9MBRBL3y3to=&lt;/DigestValue>&lt;/Reference>&lt;/SignedInfo>&lt;SignatureValue>geVzxtwW4bSbLRCEUTgIdn3xwZFnyHXLBamGlnudEwBdxpUrtlyUZBD71zpbP85AIuoFTNPsAGwDsknaRa5jhurDIJ2AsR2rsOh8dlnFDEwCK76zldPVXWIVIat255ShMDRLG3dlBDuHN1h8rdBihKrMD2tfS4xJ8KAI1+jwhaeM8/RYIFktCQUhjnUszmiChOfiqSl+a0aitgboGmP9blDrZcEu8UflslAgnmRr0mRg3NP8JoRqhNH/XuqEXNJUihuGmGqK8pwbSQpPGMl2qmBk20F3lliOFXcToQCFHBMY52c4jix2X8yxvFTU5Wx0JLYqoOo8FKPBEwfPtGD01g==&lt;/SignatureValue>&lt;KeyInfo>&lt;X509Data>&lt;X509Certificate>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&lt;/X509Certificate>&lt;/X509Data>&lt;/KeyInfo>&lt;/Signature>&lt;/saml:Assertion>&lt;/t:RequestedSecurityToken>&lt;t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion&lt;/t:TokenType>&lt;t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue&lt;/t:RequestType>&lt;t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey&lt;/t:KeyType>&lt;/t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>" /><input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="wa=wsignin1.0&amp;rpsnv=4&amp;ct=1417199483&amp;rver=6.1.6206.0&amp;wp=MBI&amp;wreply=https:%2F%2Fsomethingonline.sharepoint.com%2F_forms%2Fdefault.aspx&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=500046&amp;bk=1417199484&amp;LoginOptions=3" /><noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form><script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script></body></html>`

I get the above response when I am within the domain else I get the html for custom login page as smart links has been configured. I am not sure if I am posting to the right url.How do I get to to the response with `BinarySecurityToken`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved .I tracked the requests and responses by `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class in CSOM using fiddler and followed the same.
[Reference](http://mycognizances.blogspot.com/2016/07/How-to-authenticate-to-sharepoint-online.html)