# Remote login to O365 which is integrated with ADFS

Tags: office-365

I am trying to authenticate to O365 using Jquery as like in the [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122717/remote-authentication-using-rest/122744#122744?newreg=d95af67466ae4331867b932e86101a5e)

Am not sure about the SAML data passing is right.Please guide me here. 
Also it will be helpful if i get the current login user details.

I cannot use the OAuth since dont have access to register my app.

Comment: Can you provide what code you have tried with so we can provide input?

Comment: Maybe the ADAL libraries will help instead? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/